# Detecting link clicked in UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have a `UIWebView` in my iPhone app that have a web page with few button, and every button has a special `URL`.

Is there any way to detect when a URL has been clicked in this specific `UIWebView`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
-(void)ButtonPressed:(id)sender {

UIButton *btnCurrent = (UIButton*)sender;
NSLog(@"sender%@",sender);

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",btnCurrent.tag];
    strRID =str;
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    NSURL *urldata = [NSURL URLWithString:strLink];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:urldata];
    [self.webRegister setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [self.webRegister loadRequest:request];
    [request release]; 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    strLink=@"";
     }
 }
```